# Irregular crash when creating NSManagedObject out of NSSet

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, custom-keyboard

I have an irregular crash (1 in 5 times on devices, 4 in 5 times on Simulator). I have set an exception breakpoint and it occurs on the following line without any console information:

```swift
if let carColorSet = car.carToDisplay?.allObjects as? [Display] {
```

**Note: `car.carToDisplay` is an NSSet**

Before I set the exception breakpoint, I would get the following info in the console when it crashed:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableSet unionSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e79b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001023d6141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102e00051 -[NSMutableSet unionSet:] + 1041
    3   CoreData                            0x0000000101b10df8 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willReadWithContents:] + 936
    4   CoreData                            0x0000000101af131b -[_NSFaultingMutableSet allObjects] + 27
    5   Keyboard                            0x00000001018f838e
```

Any idea here? It seems like the crash occurs when I try to turn that `carToDisplay?.allObjects` into an array of `Display` objects.

This is a keyboard extension app btw.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: The line of code pointed by you seems to be ok as it uses `if let` and `as?` Also the exception clearly states that exception is caused when `unionSet` is invoked on an `NSMutableSet` instance Set an exception breakpoint, so that Xcode will stop at the line of the exception. Find out the line and the update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: @user1046037 Thank you! I have set the exception breakpoint and updated my question with the result.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem (probably):

```
if let carColorSet = car.carToDisplay?.allObjects as? [Display]
```

`carToDisplay` is a `NSet`
However the function `allObjects` returns an array

I think you are trying to do a unionSet with an array.

## Update the Question:

Please update your question, the qestion doesn't state the correct line of error.

The question needs to do the following

- state where the unionSet is invoked.
- what the argument type of unionSet is.